# how to detect center of a blurry circle with opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I have got the following image:

[image]

There are curves on the picture.
i would like to find center of the circles containing curves.

i tried opencv and hough circle transform but had no results.

Comment: Possibly a better question for [DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It looks like the center is actually outside the image, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, center is outside, but i use bigger picture with this one in the middle when i use hough circle transform.

Answer (score 1):

The natural candidate would be `cvHoughCircles`. Each part of each curve adds a "vote" for an `X/Y/R` triplet which identifies the centrepoint. Now, you only have part of the circles, so the number of votes is limited and the accuracy reduced, but you probably suspected as much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would try first:

Observe that if you draw rays from the true center of the circles, the local maxima of the image intensity along them occur at intervals that are independent of the ray orientation. These intervals are the differences between the lengths of the radii of consecutive circles.

So fix a number or ray directions, say 16 equally spaced in [0, pi], and define a cost function parametrized on the (xc, yc) coordinates of the center, and the ri radii of the circles, with cost equal to, for example, the variance of the maxima locations along the radii 
among different radii.

Answer (score 0):

- Threshold the image
- erode it until there is little or no noise (small blobs)
- dilate it back
- find the big blob. If there are still some small blobs, select the max area.
- use cv::moments to find its centroid